# Sort column into rows of eight cells

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know if it's possible to do it,
I need to copy data from sheet 2 from column B with a variable range,
selecting 8 lines at a time from sheet 2,
pasting with transposition in sheet 1 starting from row 9 onwards? thank you

````
Sub copy()
Sheets(2).Range("B1:B8").Copy
With Sheets(1).Range("B9:I9")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End With
Sheets(2).Range("B9:B16").Copy
With Sheets(1).Range("B10:I10")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End With
Sheets(2).Range("B17:B24").Copy
With Sheets(1).Range("B11:I11")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End With
Sheets(2).Range("B25:B32").Copy
With Sheets(1).Range("B12:I12")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End With


Application.CutCopyMode = True
 End Sub  ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code assumes that the range we want to copy and paste is always the same and always 8 rows.

I assume the original data looks like this:

[image]

Then we can copy and transpose the range to this:

[image]

by using this code:

```
Sub Copy_paste_transpose()

Dim lrow_copy As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim rows_to_copy As Long

lrow_copy = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet2

i = 9 'Start pasting at row 9
rows_to_copy = 7 'always "remove" one row.

For j = 1 To lrow_copy Step 8 'Loop through range and "jump" 8 rows at each looping.
    Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(j, "B"), Sheets(2).Cells(j + rows_to_copy, "B")).Copy 'Copy range
    Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2), Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2 + rows_to_copy)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True 'Paste range and transpose the copied range
    
    i = i + 1 'add one row after each paste

Next j

Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Deselect last copy selection

End Sub
```

Comment: No need to paste (Special) in a range having the same number of elements. You can paste in one cell and Excel does the job as it needs. It is necessary to do that only if you use an array...

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```vb
Sub copy()
    Const PERIOD = 8, PASTE_FROM_ROW = 9
    Dim last_row As Long, i As Long
    
    last_row = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 0 To last_row \ PERIOD - 1
        Sheets(1).Cells(PASTE_FROM_ROW + i, "B").Resize(, PERIOD) = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(2).Cells(i * PERIOD + 1, "B").Resize(PERIOD))
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Transpose a Column

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeColumn()
    Const ProcName As String = "TransposeColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const sID As Variant = 2 ' or "Sheet2"
    Const sFirst As String = "B1"
    
    Const dID As Variant = 1 ' or "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "B9"
    Const dcCount As Long = 8
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source First Cell Range.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sID)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirst)
    
    ' Using the 'GetTransposedColumn' function, write the transposed data
    ' to the Destination Array.
    Dim dData As Variant: dData = GetTransposedColumn(sfCell, dcCount)
    If IsEmpty(dData) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination First Cell Range.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dID)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    
    ' Check if the values from the Destination Array fit
    ' into the Destination Worksheet.
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = UBound(dData, 1)
    If drCount > dws.Rows.Count - dfCell.Row + 1 Then Exit Sub
    If dcCount > dws.Columns.Count - dfCell.Column + 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the Destination Array to the Destination Range.
    drg.Value = dData
    
    ' Clear the contents below the Destination Range.
    With drg
        Dim crCount As Long: crCount = .Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1
        If crCount > drCount Then
            .Resize(crCount - drCount).Offset(drCount).ClearContents
        End If
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Data transposed.", vbInformation, ProcName
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
        & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
        & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the transposed values of a one-column range
'               in a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetTransposedColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnsCount As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetTransposedColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If ColumnsCount < 1 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        srCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim sData As Variant
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        sData = srg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dcrCount As Long: dcrCount = Int(srCount / ColumnsCount)
    Dim dcRem As Long: dcRem = srCount Mod ColumnsCount
    Dim drCount As Long
    If dcRem = 0 Then
        drCount = dcrCount
    Else
        drCount = dcrCount + 1
    End If
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To ColumnsCount)
        
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    If dcrCount > 0 Then
        For r = 1 To dcrCount
            For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                n = n + 1
                dData(r, c) = sData(n, 1)
            Next c
        Next r
    Else
        r = 1
    End If
    
    If dcRem > 0 Then
        For c = 1 To dcRem
            n = n + 1
            dData(r, c) = sData(n, 1)
        Next c
    End If
    
    GetTransposedColumn = dData

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
        & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
        & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```